# Writing multiple values in single cell in csv

Tags: python, csv

For each user I have the list of events in which he participated.
e.g. bob : [event1,event2,...]

I want to write it in csv file. I created a dictionary (key - user  & value - list of events)
I wrote it in csv. The following is the sample output

```
username, frnds
"abc"     ['event1','event2']
```

where username is first col and frnds 2nd col

This is code

```
writer = csv.writer(open('eventlist.csv', 'ab'))
for key, value in evnt_list.items():
    writer.writerow([key, value])
```

when I am reading the csv I am not getting the list directly. But I am getting it in following way

```
['e','v','e','n','t','1','','...]
```

I also tried to write the list directly in csv but while reading am getting the same output.

What I want is multiple values in a single cell so that when I read a column for a row I get list of all events.

```
e.g
colA  colB
user1,event1,event2,...
```

I think it's not difficult but somehow I am not getting it.

###Reading

I am reading it with the help of following

```
codereader = csv.reader(open("eventlist.csv")) 
reader.next() 
for row in reader: 
    tmp=row[1] 
    print tmp # it is printing the whole list but 
        print tmp[0] #the output is [ 
        print tmp[1] #output is 'e' it should have been 'event1'
        print tmp[2] #output is 'v' it should have been 'event2'
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to format your values into a single string:

```
with open('eventlist.csv', 'ab') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    for key, value in evnt_list.items():
        writer.writerow([key, ','.join(value)])
```

exports as

```
key1 val11,val12,val13
key2 val21,val22,val23
```

**READING:** Here you have to keep in mind, that you converted your Python list into a formatted string. Therefore you cannot use standard csv tools to read it:

```
with open("eventlist.csv") as f:
    csvr = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ') 
    csvr.next() 
    for rec in csvr: 
        key, values_txt = rec 
        values = values_txt.split(',')
        print key, values
```

works as awaited.

Comment: I have edited my question. You can find my problem while reading the csv.

Comment: thanks for sample code. I modified it according to my need and  my problem is solved.

Comment: You actually can still use the `csv` module to process the multivalued cell: `values = csv.reader([values_txt]).next()`. This would be useful in cases where `values_txt` is too complex for `split` to handle on its own. (I realize the problem as presented here is not one of those cases.)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying that your `evnt_list` is a dictionary whose keys are strings and whose values are lists of strings.  If so, then the CSV-writing code you've given in your question will write a string representation of a Python list into the second column.  When you read anything in from CSV, it will just be a string, so once again you'll have a string representation of your list.  For example, if you have a cell that contains `"['event1', 'event2']"` you will be reading in a string whose first character (at position 0) is `[`, second character is `'`, third character is `e`, etc.  (I don't think your `tmp[1]` is right; I think it is really `'`, not `e`.)

It sounds like you want to reconstruct the Python object, in this case a list of strings.  To do that, use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

cell_string_value = "['event1', 'event2']"
cell_object = ast.literal_eval(cell_string_value)
```

Incidentally, the reason to use `ast.literal_eval` instead of just `eval` is safety. `eval` allows arbitrary Python expressions and is thus a security risk.

Also, what is the purpose of the CSV, if you want to get the list back as a list?  Will people be reading it (in Excel or something)?  If not, then you may want to simply save the `evnt_list` object using `pickle` or `json`, and not bother with the CSV at all.

**Edit:** I should have read more carefully; the data from `evnt_list` is being *appended* to the CSV, and neither `pickle` nor `json` is easily appendable.  So I suppose CSV is a reasonable and lightweight way to accumulate the data.  A full-blown database might be better, but that would not be as lightweight.

Comment: I am doing research in recommendation systems. Currently I am creating scrappers to scrap the data.Next, I will be  applying various algorithms on this data to find patterns.